# AngularJS: can't set innerHTML of element after ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, innerhtml

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="custom-select">
    <div class="custom-select-placeholder">
        <span id="placeholder-pages">Show all posts</span> 
    </div>
    <ul class="custom-select-list animate-show no-padding no-margin" >
        <li ng-click="selectItem($event)">Show all posts</li>
        <li ng-click="selectItem($event)">Events</li>
        <li ng-click="selectItem($event)">Files</li>
        <li ng-click="selectItem($event)">Pictures</li>
        <li ng-click="selectItem($event)">Thoughts</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on a 'li' item, I need to fetch its innerHTML and set the innerHTML of the span having its id as 'placeholder-pages' to the value fetched.

For this I wrote the following function in my controller:

```
$scope.selectItem = function(evt) {
        var selected = evt.target.innerHTML; //working
        var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder-pages'); //working
        placeholder.innerHTML = selected; //not working
}
```

In the function I am able to get the innerHTML of the 'li' selected and also the 'placeholder-pages' div. But I cannot set the div's innerHTML. I am not getting any error. Nothing happens.

Comment: wish i could help more, but you should not need innerHTML if you are working with angular - you are making things harder for your self than you need to

Comment: Yes, actually I solved it using ng-bind, but I was curious why the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using **ng-bind**.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="custom-select-placeholder">
    <span id="placeholder-pages" ng-bind="selected_option"></span> //set html using ng-bind
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.selected_option = 'Show all posts';

$scope.selectItem = function(evt) {
        var selected = evt.target.innerHTML; 
        $scope.selected_option = selected;
}
```

I guess this is a more 'Angular' way of doing things as suggested by @Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Checked it in Chrome (v45) , FF (v39) and even IE9 - everything works perfectly (Angular version is 1.3.14), placeholder properly receives the innerHTML data and displays it.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon already said you should use ng-bind instead. As a rule of thumb all DOM access and manipulation belong to a `directive` link function.

BTW.
Your code works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/PB5P2dhDD836mkssVlOo?p=preview

Comment: yes I used ng-bind instead. Also, I have no idea why it is not working in my code. :/